# Is there any web layout paradigm that makes CSS a little bit less... unpredictable?

Tags: html, css, layout

What motivates me to write this question is that I'm really into making good appearing web-sites but I definetly do not feel confortable with CSS.

My feeling is that it's all about trial-and-error. I need to try to do something and test, test and then test it over again in all browsers and after all I still have a feeling that the result isn't that cross-browser.

**I can't find a way to systematically transform an idea in a consistent layout that is easy to read and cross-browser**.

So I'm asking you: Is there a paradigm, a step-by-step guide or anything that could help me having the feeling that I'm doing it the right way?

Comment: welcome to the world of web design :)

Comment: @AUSteve: You must not work with very good designers.

Comment: @Esteban Araya: who does?      :)

Comment: @AUSteve: Yeah, you're right. :)

Comment: @Esteban - the better the designer, the more impossible it is to code for them.

Comment: @Joel: So what are the people that are really good at photoshop and also really good at HTML and CSS called? I need to find more of those people. :)

Comment: @Esteban: There's more to it than that though. I'm pretty excellent with Photoshop, HTML is easy, and I can make CSS sing most of the of time. But I'm teh suk at design. You are right though. We do need more people good at all of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Object Oriented CSS](http://wiki.github.com/stubbornella/oocss/). Their approach is really methodical; pages makes sense just by looking at the markup. The layout component is particularly good.

For example:

```
 <div class="line">
  <div class="unit size1of2">
    <h3>1/2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="unit size1of2 lastUnit">
    <h3>1/2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Doesn't the markup above just make sense? You can find more Grid samples [here](http://wiki.github.com/stubbornella/oocss/grids).

Also, you should probably know that OOCSS is built upon the CSS Reset Stylesheet and Fonts from the YUI library. Although OCSSS has no real "styles" defined, it provides a great foundation to make your CSS more predictable and consistent.

Comment: ... and that will lead to more bloated HTML, as well as introduce presentational tagging - is that really better?

Comment: @K Prime: I see your point, and I really don't care that much about either of the issues you bring up. However, the OP asked for a way to make his markup more consistent, and I think OOCSS does so.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using a CSS reset stylesheet, like [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). With this starting point, everything 1) starts to make a little more sense and 2) doesn't have as many cross-browser issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds simple, but this is some of the best advice i ever read:

[A List Apart: Articles: Fix Your Site With the Right DOCTYPE!](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/)

Comment: i was serious... sorry if it was taken he wrong way. doctype really does fix several x-browser issues.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a CSS framework (and a CSS reset, which usually is available nearby -- see Yahoo's or Eric Meyer's).  Yahoo makes an excellent one called [Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/).  It's a personal favorite and I use it frequently.  Other popular choices are the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/) and [Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/).

If you're really hungry, consider checking out [even more](http://speckyboy.com/2008/03/28/top-12-css-frameworks-and-how-to-understand-them/) [other options](http://www.noupe.com/css/5-popular-css-frameworks-tutorials-tools-for-getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using a CSS "framework" is a good start.  [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) and [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/) are both good and adaptable.  [Object Oriented CSS](http://wiki.github.com/stubbornella/oocss/) is also interesting, but always struck me as a better presentation and theory than as an actual starting place.  I still prefer using a css framework.

Basically, the idea with a framework is it starts with a complete reset and then provides concrete styles that you can apply to an element very reasonable certainty that it will look that way in every supported browser.  The downside is that if you're trying to adapt an existing design (that's not [grid-based](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/04/14/designing-with-grid-based-approach/)) it's very tough using a framework, but the reset sheets are still a great starting place, and you can use the rest for pointers.